# What causes delays in removing bad posts/answers?

Tags: discussion, moderation

[This post](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/4642/233) has been up for 4-5 days now.  I flagged it originally when it was first posted and that flag aged away, I have now flagged it again and it's still here.  We have one [user](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/users/1263/szymon-b%C4%99czkowski) that shares part of the posters name but I am unsure if they are connected in any way or if that name references the linked user.

Do we need more moderators to handle this?  What is the process for having these removed?

Answer (score 1):

The post has now been deleted and the user destroyed due to spam, so thank you for bringing this up.

It either must have come up after I cleaned out the inbox or I must have overlooked it.

Yes, we do need another moderator. I would have loved to be at a point by now that we could have had elections as part of a fully public SE site, but we've still got a few hurdles to overcome as a community.

I'll double check what the options are for bringing on new moderators at this stage and post back to Meta.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as I'm 20 days late to this question, you probably understand that I'm not very active at the moment myself. (At least, I'm inactive for longer periods of time.) With Ryan gone for almost a year now, that often leaves @tbm0115 as the only moderator on this site.

In other words, we could do with another moderator or a change of moderators (Ryan and perhaps me also).

On the plus side, we are getting more and more users, which makes the community handle a lot of cases by itself.

Comment: @Oded, Is it possible to run an election or replace moderators during the beta phase?